# Syntax Error Python: Unexpected Indent

Tags: python, pygame

I recently started learning Python. I am unable to resolve this error:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:

        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

        pygame.display.update()
```

I get an error that says

> unexpected indent

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not in English

Comment: FYI: http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: As the error message says, your code is not indented correctly. You should put error messages into the question as text, not as a linked image.

Comment: Thank you! Next I ask in English.

Comment: Statements that you want to be executed after matching the `if` should be further indented, so probably the next two code lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move right this part:

```
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```